# How to tell ccc-analyzer (C static analyzer in clang) that a function cannot return

Tags: clang, clang-static-analyzer

I am currently using `ccc-analyzer` by means of `static-build` to analyze our code base. I am using a recent build I made from the Git mirror.

Now in PC-Lint I am able to tell Lint whenever a function doesn't return. This is usually done via `/*lint -unreachable*/` or similar comments ("markup") that control the PC-Lint behavior.

With `scan-build` I am now running across a number of false positives that I would like to suppress, because I know that a particular function will never return (ultimately it calls the `exit` function of the C runtime). Is there any way to tell `static-build`/`ccc-analyzer` that my function *cannot* return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a way to annotate the code using GCC-style attributes as [documented here](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html#attr_analyzer_noreturn). So the question is answered.